# Anti-captcha response to form

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I'm trying to pass the form from https://supremenewyork.com/checkout
(If web page is redirecting you to the shop, add some item and try again)

It has reCAPTCHA, so I decided to use anti-captcha.com service.
I've successfully figured out requests to get captcha response by sitekey and web page link (https://supremenewyork.com/checkout), but how I could use it on the page?

I've tried this code:

```js
$('script[src="https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/api2/v1520836262157/recaptcha__ru.js"]').remove()
$('script[src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"]').remove()
$('.g-recaptcha').remove()

for (let i = 0; i < $('body > div').length; i++) {
  if ($('body > div').eq(i).find('iframe').length > 0) {
    if ($('body > div').eq(i).find('iframe').attr('src').indexOf('www.google.com/recaptcha') > -1) {
      $('body > div').eq(i).find('iframe').remove()
    }
  }
}

$('[name=\'commit\']')
  .before(`<textarea style="display:none;" name="g-recaptcha-response">"""${captcha_response}</textarea>`)
```

But it's not working. When I push "process payment" button, it redirects me to the page like "Your card has been declined", but if you check outgoing requests by Network tab in browser, you'll see that in response checkout.json there will be 'Failure Reason:null' - it means that request have been made incorrectly. For correct requests Network tab shows status.json, where 'Failure Reason' may be 'Credit Card' or something like that.

Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: It's almost as though the CAPTCHA is supposed to stop you from doing this… 

Comment: @duskwuff some other people have already bypassed captcha by doing something like this. I only can't figure out how to use response correctly.

Comment: are you creating cc checker ?